# Bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha3 Rails 4.2.5 Bootstrap btn pull-right doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Kindly assist me by pointing out why the button created below will not take its position to the right of the webpage. I have this code in index.html.erb

```
<div class = "page-header">
    <%= link_to "New Product" , new_product_path , :class => "btn btn-success pull-right" %>
    <h3>All Products</h3>
</div>

<div class = ''row">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 text-center">
        <h2><%= product.name %></h2>
        <img class = "img-responsive" src = <%= asset_path product.featImage %>/>
        <p><%= product.description %></p>
        <h4>$<%= product.price %></h4>
        <%= link_to "Show" , product , :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>`enter code here`
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I would include a fiddle if possible.

Comment: You need to post your rendered HTML (along with any additional CSS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) so there's an actual working example that demonstrates the problem. See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I changed back to the latest 3 series previous gem version. i.e. Bootstrap-sass 3.3.6

In the Gemfile write this :

## Bootstrap.

gem "bootstrap-sass" , "~> 3.3.6"

This will resolve the issue. It seems that Bootstrap 4.0.0 aplha3 does not support "class = "btn btn-success pull-right" "